# issue with 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, .net, software-design, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

I started to create a project for practice purpose and I thought I should have 3 tier programming structure.

I wanted to create a memberinfo system in which I have a presentationClass , MemberBusinessLayer class and 3rd dataLayer.

I said to myself My PresentationLayer should only contact with MemberBusinessLayer class to get the data and MemberBusinessLayer class should get the data from me from dayalayer class. However i saw problem..

In BusinessLayer class I have public member properties for example FirstName, LastName, Address.

In DataLayer class I created a method  Public List GetMember(string) . and in my design there is a method  SendDataToPresntationLayer() in BusinessLayer class that is calling a GetMembe() method of dataLayer class. I see that is wrong. I am trying to get GetMember returns BusinessLayer object and I am calling getmember in BusinessLayer class.

Well I don't think I can't work with only 3 classes. My design is wrong. There is something more that I need to do.  Can somoene help me.  Please I am trying to learn I might be very much wrong but I am trying.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question suggests a very complex answer.
While this question is for practice purpose try to read Design recomendations. 
You can start from this guide http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16236